# How to define a nice jetbrains live template for angular 2 components

Tags: angular, intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

I already have this live template on my Jetbrains IntelliJ for rapidly creating an angular 2 component:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
 moduleId: module.id,
 selector: '$selector$',
 templateUrl: '$name$.component.html'
})
export class $ComponentName$Component implements OnInit {
 constructor() { }

 ngOnInit() { }
$END$
}
```

But unfortunately, it's not fast enough. The system already knows the file name(defined by the user) and should be able to set the values for the "templateUrl","selector" and "ClassName" automatically. However, I was not able to find a solution despite reading live template documentation on predefined functions [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.2/creating-and-editing-template-variables.html#predefined_functions).

Here is the best solution came to my mind. But unfortunately I have to type the $nameonly$ despite the fact that the name is already in component name:

```js
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {MeteorComponent} from "angular2-meteor";
import template from './$name$.html';

@Component({
 selector: '$nameonly$',
 template
})
export class $uppername$Component extends MeteorComponent {
 constructor() {
 super(); 
 }
$END$
}
```

[image]